# Search one CSV file in another csv file and update column value in first csv

Tags: python, csv

I have two csv files.
Search.csv file has few columns and I want to search it in input.csv, and if it exists then update row value in input.csv to 'Yes'.
I tried:

```
f1=pd.read_csv("input.csv")
f2=pd.read_csv("search.csv")
with open(result.csv,'w')as result:
 res=f1[~f1.apply(tuple,1)isin(f2.apply(tuple,1))]
 print(inp)
```

Input.csv

| Name | IP | Protocol | Port | Exists |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| l1 | 192.132.16.02 | HTTP | 80 |  |
| l2 | 192.132.16.03 | HTTP | 80 |  |
| l3 | 192.132.16.03 | SSL | 443 |  |
| l4 | 192.132.16.04 | SSL | 443 |  |

search.csv

| N0 | Protocol | IP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HTTP | 192.132.16.02 |
| 2 | HTTP | 192.132.16.03 |
| 3 | SSL | 192.132.16.03 |

I have to go through each line in search.csv and look for it in input.csv based on columns 'IP' and 'Protocol'. If it is a match, then update the column 'Exists' in input.csv to 'Yes'.
Please suggest how to achieve this using python.
I am new to python. Please help

Comment: Can you show us some code with what you have tried so far? I would suggest using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) package. Open booth files at the same time. And write the result back to a new third file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the `csv` module to do it because it makes handling them relatively easy. In this particular case I decided to use its `DictReader` and `DictWriter` objects because they allow the fields of each row to be accessed symbolically via a dictionary key which make it easier to keep track of what you're doing in the code.

The entire input.csv file is read into a list in memory because it needs to be traversed multiple times (once for each row in the search.csv file) and any updates made need to be store somewhere until they're written back out to a file.

```
import csv

IP, EXISTS, PROTOCOL = 'IP', 'Exists', 'Protocol'  # Field names referenced.

# Read entire input file into a list.
with open('input.csv', 'r', newline='') as inp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inp)
    inputs = list(reader)

# Update input rows that match data in search.csv file.
with open('search.csv', 'r', newline='') as sea:
    sea_reader = csv.DictReader(sea)
    for row in sea_reader:
        protocol, ip = row[PROTOCOL], row[IP]
        for input_ in inputs:
            if input_[PROTOCOL] == protocol and input_[IP] == ip:  # Match?
                input_[EXISTS] = 'Yes'
                break

# Write updated input.csv data out into a file.
with open('input_updated.csv', 'w', newline='') as outp:
    fieldnames = inputs[0].keys()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outp, fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(inputs)

print('done')
```